# Plugin changing maven coordinates

Tags: artifactory, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to create a maven script that build an app and deploys to Artifactory (cloud) running from Bitbucket pipelines (cloud).

When I build locally, the artifact is stored correctly in the local repository. When the pipeline runs, it adds the repository to the Maven group id. The build then fails, I believe since it can't find it after storing it. The artifact does make it into Artifactory, just with the wrong coordinates.

**What I'd expect the coordinates to look like**:

```
<groupId>edu.dkist</groupId>
<artifactId>artifactory-hello</artifactId>
<version>1.0-20180319.211356-1</version>
```

**But what I'm getting** is

```
<groupId>dkistdc-snapshots.edu.dkist</groupId>
<artifactId>artifactory-hello</artifactId>
<version>1.0-20180319.211356-1</version>
```

**dkistdc-snapshots** is the name of the repository.

I'm pretty much using the examples provided, but the builds are failing. Here's a hello world app as an example.

The **POM file** I'm using is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>edu.dkist</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactory-hello</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>dkistdc-releases</name>
            <url>https://dkistdc.jfrog.io/dkistdc/java/dkistdc-releases</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>dkistdc-snapshots</name>
            <url>https://dkistdc.jfrog.io/dkistdc/java/dkistdc-snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputFile>
                                ${project.build.outputDirectory}/dkist-producer.properties
                            </outputFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jfrog.buildinfo</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifactory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-info</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>publish</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <deployProperties>
                                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                <version>${project.version}</version>
                            </deployProperties>
                            <artifactory>
                                <includeEnvVars>true</includeEnvVars>
                                <timeoutSec>60</timeoutSec>
                                <propertiesFile>publish.properties</propertiesFile>
                            </artifactory>
                            <publisher>
                                <contextUrl>${url}</contextUrl>
                                <username>${username}</username>
                                <password>${password}</password>
                                <excludePatterns>*-tests.jar</excludePatterns>
                                <repoKey>dkistdc-releases</repoKey>
                                <snapshotRepoKey>dkistdc-snapshots</snapshotRepoKey>
                            </publisher>
                            <buildInfo>
                                <buildName>artifactory-hello</buildName>
                                <buildNumber>${buildnumber}</buildNumber>
                                <buildUrl>http://dkist.nso.edu</buildUrl>
                            </buildInfo>
                            <licenses>
                                <autoDiscover>true</autoDiscover>
                                <includePublishedArtifacts>false</includePublishedArtifacts>
                                <runChecks>true</runChecks>
                                <scopes>compile,runtime</scopes>
                            </licenses>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The **pipelines script** I'm using is

```
image: maven:3.3-jdk-8

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - maven
        script: 
          - chmod 777 deploy-to-artifactory.bash
          - ./deploy-to-artifactory.bash
        deployment: test
```

And the **deploy-to-artifactory** script is

```
#!/bin/bash -ex

if [ -z "$buildNumber" ]; then
    buildNumber=`date +%s`
fi

mvn install -DskipTests=true
mvn test
mvn deploy -Dusername=${ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME} -Dpassword=${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD} -Durl=${ARTIFACTORY_CONTEXT_URL}
```

The **errors I'm seeing** in the logs are

```
[INFO] Artifactory Build Info Recorder: Saving Build Info to 

'/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/target/build-info.json'
[INFO] Deploying artifact: https://dkistdc.jfrog.io/dkistdc/java/dkistdc-snapshots/edu/dkist/artifactory-hello/1.0-SNAPSHOT/artifactory-hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Response received: 




[ERROR] Failed while reading the response from: PUT https://dkistdc.jfrog.io/dkistdc/java/dkistdc-snapshots/edu/dkist/artifactory-hello/1.0-SNAPSHOT/artifactory-hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.sha1;groupId=edu.dkist;artifactId=artifactory-hello;build.timestamp=1521494036708;build.name=dkist-producer;build.number=1521494036708;version=1.0-SNAPSHOT HTTP/1.1
java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2775)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2691)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1286)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser.readValueAs(JsonParser.java:1337)
    at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.execute(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:209)
    at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.upload(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:195)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadChecksums(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:638)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:285)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deployArtifacts(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:275)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deploy(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:98)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded(BuildInfoRecorder.java:170)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:64)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] Response received: 




[ERROR] Failed while reading the response from: PUT https://dkistdc.jfrog.io/dkistdc/java/dkistdc-snapshots/edu/dkist/artifactory-hello/1.0-SNAPSHOT/artifactory-hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.md5;groupId=edu.dkist;artifactId=artifactory-hello;build.timestamp=1521494036708;build.name=dkist-producer;build.number=1521494036708;version=1.0-SNAPSHOT HTTP/1.1
java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2775)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2691)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1286)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser.readValueAs(JsonParser.java:1337)
    at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.execute(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:209)
    at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.upload(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:195)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadChecksums(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:653)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:285)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deployArtifacts(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:275)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deploy(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:98)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded(BuildInfoRecorder.java:170)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:64)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] Deploying artifact: https://dkistdc.jfrog.io/dkistdc/java/dkistdc-snapshots/edu/dkist/artifactory-hello/1.0-SNAPSHOT/artifactory-hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Response received: 




[ERROR] Failed while reading the response from: PUT https://dkistdc.jfrog.io/dkistdc/java/dkistdc-snapshots/edu/dkist/artifactory-hello/1.0-SNAPSHOT/artifactory-hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom.sha1;groupId=edu.dkist;artifactId=artifactory-hello;build.timestamp=1521494036708;build.name=dkist-producer;build.number=1521494036708;version=1.0-SNAPSHOT HTTP/1.1
java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2775)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2691)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1286)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser.readValueAs(JsonParser.java:1337)
    at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.execute(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:209)
    at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.upload(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:195)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadChecksums(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:638)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:285)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deployArtifacts(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:275)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deploy(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:98)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded(BuildInfoRecorder.java:170)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:64)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] Response received: 




[ERROR] Failed while reading the response from: PUT https://dkistdc.jfrog.io/dkistdc/java/dkistdc-snapshots/edu/dkist/artifactory-hello/1.0-SNAPSHOT/artifactory-hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom.md5;groupId=edu.dkist;artifactId=artifactory-hello;build.timestamp=1521494036708;build.name=dkist-producer;build.number=1521494036708;version=1.0-SNAPSHOT HTTP/1.1
java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2775)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2691)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1286)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser.readValueAs(JsonParser.java:1337)
    at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.execute(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:209)
    at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.upload(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:195)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadChecksums(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:653)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:285)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deployArtifacts(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:275)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deploy(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:98)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded(BuildInfoRecorder.java:170)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:64)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] Artifactory Build Info Recorder: Deploying build info ...
[ERROR] Could not build the build-info object.
org.jfrog.build.util.VersionException: There is either an incompatible or no instance of Artifactory at the provided URL.
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.verifyCompatibleArtifactoryVersion(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:304)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.buildInfoToJsonString(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:515)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.sendBuildInfo(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:194)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deploy(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:111)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded(BuildInfoRecorder.java:170)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:64)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded() listener has failed: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while publishing Build Info to Artifactory.
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deploy(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:114)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded(BuildInfoRecorder.java:170)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:64)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not publish build-info: There is either an incompatible or no instance of Artifactory at the provided URL.
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.sendBuildInfo(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:197)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deploy(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:111)
    ... 18 more
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded() listener has failed: Error occurred while publishing Build Info to Artifactory. Could not publish build-info: There is either an incompatible or no instance of Artifactory at the provided URL. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded() listener has failed: 
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded() listener has failed: 
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded(BuildInfoRecorder.java:179)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:64)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while publishing Build Info to Artifactory.
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deploy(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:114)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded(BuildInfoRecorder.java:170)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not publish build-info: There is either an incompatible or no instance of Artifactory at the provided URL.
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.sendBuildInfo(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:197)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deploy(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:111)
    ... 18 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/InternalErrorException
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?